# Lateral raises - shoulder blades and elbows

Tags: exercise-technique

1) Should the shoulder blades be constantly retracted or retracted at all when doing lateral raises?

2) Should the elbows be straight or have a a bend in them?

Comment: Question has been well answered by Alec but here is a explanation of the exercise: http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/DeltoidLateral/CBLateralRaise.html

Answer (score 1):

1. Retract your shoulders, and try to minimize trapezius involvement. The lateral raise is aimed at the deltoid, and the trapezius can take focus away from the primary goal.
2. Straight, but not locked out. If you find yourself bending the arm more to cope with the weight, the weight is too high. Grab something smaller.